# scale performance of method which is running on multiple threads C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Below is the code which increases the performance of a new Method which opens multiple multiple threads but the method which is called on single thread has good performance.

So could you please let me know how to minimize the time for new method which is run on multiple threads rather then the method which is run on single thread(i.e Old method)

```
        public List<CEntity> GetSomeFunction(Ent ent)
    {
        List<CEntity> lstCE = new List<CEntity>();
        this.objEnt = ent;

        TestObj  objTempBal = new objTempBal(); 
        objTempBal.objEnt = ent;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("new Method");

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        objTempBal.FetchSomeDataAsync(ent).Wait();

        stopWatch.Stop();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Elapsed time: {0} -- {1} ",
        stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds, DateTime.Now));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("old Method");

        Stopwatch stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch1.Start();

    List<CEntity> result = null;
        ResponseApi response = null;
        try
        {
            IWrapper Wrapper = InitializeWrapper(ent);
            int pageNo = 1;
            bool createPaging = true;
            while (createPaging)
            {

                SearchCriteria objSC = new SearchCriteria()
                {
                    //pageSize = this.pageSize,
                    pageSize = "1000",
                    page = pageNo.ToString()
                };
                response = Wrapper.SomeSynchronusAPIMethod(objSC);
                if (response.Success)
                {
                    result = (List<CEntity>)response.results;
                    if (result.Count == 0)
                    {
                        createPaging = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = result.ToList();                           

                    }
                    lstCE.AddRange(result);

                }
                else { createPaging = false; }
                pageNo = pageNo + 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        stopWatch1.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Elapsed time: {0} -- {1} ",
            stopWatch1.Elapsed.Milliseconds, DateTime.Now));
        return lstCE;
    }

public async Task<List<CEntity>> FetchSomeDataAsync(Ent ent)
{

        var tasks = new List<Task<List<CEntity>>>();
         int pageCount = 18;
        List<int> pages = new List<int>();

        for (int addItemToList = 1; addItemToList <= pageCount; addItemToList++)
        {
            pages.Add(addItemToList);
        }
        List<CEntity> resultRange = new List<CEntity>();
        foreach (var list in pages.Batch(10))
        {

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                IWrapper Wrapper1 = InitializeWrapper(ent);
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>  FetchSomeDataFromSynchronusAPI(Wrapper1, item)));  

            }
            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            resultRange.AddRange(results.SelectMany(x => x.ToList()).ToList());
            tasks = new List<Task<List<CEntity>>>();
        }
      return resultRange;

}

    public async Task<List<CEntity>> FetchSomeDataFromSynchronusAPI(IWrapper Wrapper, int pageNo)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start pageNo " + pageNo + " -- " + DateTime.Now);

        List<CEntity> result = null;
        ResponseApi response = null;
        SearchCriteria objSC = new SearchCriteria()
        {

            pageSize = "1000",
            page = pageNo.ToString()
        };


        response = Wrapper.SomeSynchronusAPIMethod(objSC);

        if (response.Success)
        {
            result = (List<CEntity>)response.results;

            result = result.ToList();

        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("End pageNo " + pageNo + " -- " + DateTime.Now);

        return await Task.FromResult<List<CEntity>>(result);
        //return (result);
    }
```

Comment: Wrapper.SomeSynchronusAPIMethod is this async method?

Comment: Wrapper.SomeSynchronusAPIMethod is not async method

Answer (score 2):

No need to wait for each batch. Run all the tasks and when wait for all outside the page.Batch loop.

```
          List<CEntity> resultRange = new List<CEntity>();

            foreach (var list in pages.Batch(10))
            {

                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    IWrapper Wrapper1 = InitializeWrapper(ent);
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>  FetchSomeDataFromSynchronusAPI(Wrapper1, item)));  

                }
            }

       var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
       resultRange.AddRange(results.SelectMany(x => x.ToList()).ToList());
```

Comment: If there is no need to wait for each batch then how to add the results in resultrange

Comment: I edited the answer now var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); is moved outside the loop, so the tasks list contains all tasks for all pages. results variable will contains all task results. The last line will just process all results and add them in resultrange.

Comment: But this is a flaw opening all the threads for all the pages at once will degrade the performance on the server. If there are 100 of pages then there will be 100 of threads opening on the server. So my requirement is to process threads in a batch i.e perform batch of 10 threads then 10 threads and so on

Comment: Did you find any solution?